# List to Hashset

Tags: java, hibernate, hashset

So my problem is that I dont want to have repeated names in the list of objects.

So I tried to convert the `list` to `hashset` but it still has rows with the same name.

Basically I only want to get 1 row of Flow2 and another of TestFlow NOT 4. http://prntscr.com/hylkoc

```
public static Set<TestFlow> getFlows() {
    SessionFactory factory = HibernateUtil.GetSessionFactory();
    Session hibernateSession = factory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    List<TestFlow> testFlows;
    Set<TestFlow> testFlowSet = new HashSet<>();
    try {
        tx = hibernateSession.beginTransaction();
        testFlows = hibernateSession.createQuery("FROM TestFlow").list();
        testFlowSet = new HashSet<>(testFlows);
        tx.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (tx != null) tx.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        hibernateSession.close();
    }
    return testFlowSet;
}
```

Comment: Does `TestFlow` override `equals()` and `hashCode()`? If so, please show (the relevant parts of) `TestFlow`. If not, override them.

Comment: Your `TestFlow` class must implement `equals` and only compare the `name`. `HashSet` determines whether two elements are the same based on `equals`. You can see this in [the documentation of `HashSet.add()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#add(E)). If you do not want to implement `equals`, you can use a `TreeSet` with a `Comparator` that compares `TestFlows`s by their `name`: `new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(TestFlow::getName))`

Comment: What is the Column name in the database? You need to compare the column name not entire row you got from the database.

Comment: When you have two rows with the same id, which one of the two rows do you want to keep?

Comment: which rdbms you are using?

Comment: you can use TreeSet + Comparator

Answer (score 1):

TestFlow is an object, so a record having the same name will not mean it equals the other object.

You can use a Map instead:

```
Map<String, TestFlow>
```

The key will be the name, and the value will be the TestFlow record.  That way if the name exists, you will not add the record to the map.

Another option is overriding the equals method, although if you use the object elsewhere and it has a bunch of fields, that may not be a good idea.

Comment: One notable thing about your suggested solution is that `HashMap<String, TestFlow>` does not take up any more space than `HashSet<TestFlow>`. And if you really want a set, you can easily get it using `Map.values()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TreeSet + Comparator :

**Comparator:**

```
public class TestFlowComparator implements Comparator<TestFlow> {
  @Override
  public int compare(TestFlow o1, TestFlow o2) {
    return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
  }
}
```

**Test :**

```
@Test
@DisplayName("stack")
public void srack(){
    List<TestFlow> listTestFlow = new ArrayList<>();
    listTestFlow.add(new TestFlow("a"));
    listTestFlow.add(new TestFlow("a"));
    listTestFlow.add(new TestFlow("a"));
    listTestFlow.add(new TestFlow("a"));
    listTestFlow.add(new TestFlow("ъ"));
    listTestFlow.add(new TestFlow("ъ"));

    Set<TestFlow> set = new TreeSet<>(new TestFlowComparator());
    set.addAll(listTestFlow);
    System.out.println(set.toString());
}
```

> **sout**: [TestFlow{name = a } , TestFlow{name = ъ } ]

Answer (score 0):

Inside `TestFlow` class override the two methods `equals()` and `hashCode()`.

For example if `TestFlow` class have `int id` property you can do that:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj instanceof TestFlow) {
        TestFlow tf = (TestFlow) obj;
        return tf.id == this.id;
    }
    return false;
}
```